# useQueries how to get response for a certain query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

Is it possible to distinguish the response, we get from useQueries. For example

```
const ids = ['dg1', 'pt3', 'bn5'];
const data = useQueries(
  ids.map(id => (
    {
      queryKey: ['friends', id],
      queryFn: () => get(
        '/v3/friends',
        {
          query: {
            id,
          },
        },
      ),
    }
  )),
);
```

from the response, how can I know which response is for id `dg1` and so forth or is the of the responses guaranteed to be in the same order as the ids?

Comment: `someCoolResponse.queryKey[1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order returned from `useQueries` is the same as the input order, so in your example:

- `data[0]` will be for `id: 'dg1'`
- `data[1]` will be for `id: 'pt3'`
- `data[2]` will be for `id: 'bn5'`

Comment: Is there no way to uniquely map the results to the array passed into useQueries other than the matching index? There isn't a unique id that could be associated with the results?

Comment: data will contain whatever you return from the queryFn. If you add the `queryKey` passed there, or any other unique id, it will be part of `data`

Comment: Is this included in the current docs of react query? I couldn't find that on the official docs of `useQueries`